# Running apache with the doc root as an SMB share

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, samba

I'm in Ubuntu 10.10, just mounted my new NAS in the /media directory. I then proceeded to add a new DNS entry called newtesting.cdw, and added this as a virtual host to my apache (using webmin).

When I try to access the address, it doesn't work, it will go to cufon.cdw, which is defined above newtesting.cdw in my webmin control panel.

I've set it to accept any port:

```
 Virtual Server  Handles the name-based server on address newtesting.cdw.
Address newtesting.cdw
Port Any    Server Name Automatic
Document Root /mount/magneto/testing.cdw/
```

and the results of the dig command are fine:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;newtesting.cdw.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
newtesting.cdw.         38400   IN      A       192.168.1.101
```

Just not having any luck when I visit the address in the browser. 
Does anyone have any ideas of what I should try to get this going? Is there a problem running the apache root from a NAS?

Answer (score 1):

### It Works!

The problem was I pointed it to /mount/ when I should have been using /media/

Just to confirm to anyone with the same question, you can run apache on your server and have it serve pages from a samba mounted NAS